# Reading and writing large arrays to and from .txt files

Tags: php, arrays

I'm trying to execute the code below and I keep on getting a message reading `killed` when I load the file in my terminal. I'm aware that I'm using lots of memory, so I set the memory limit to the maximum amount allowed on apache. I have a text file called `codes.txt` that contains a list of numbers from 0 to 1000000. I need to randomize the occurrence of these numbers and then write the new order of them to a new text file. Then, I need to store the new occurrence of them in an array.

```
ini_set('memory_limit', '2048M');

// Get all of the values from the .txt file 
// and store them in an array
$file = fopen("codes.txt", "r");
$codes = array();

while(!feof($file)) {
    $codes[] = trim(fgets($file));
}

fclose($file);

// Randomize the elements in the array
shuffle($codes);

// Write each element in the shuffled array to a new .txt file
$new_file = fopen("new_codes.txt", "w");

for($i=0;$i<1000000;$i++) {
      fwrite($new_file, $codes[$i].PHP_EOL);
}

fclose($new_file);

// Put all of the new elements into a new array
$new_file = fopen("new_codes.txt", "r");
$code = array();

while(!feof($new_file)) {
    $code[] = trim(fgets($new_file));
}

print_r($code);
```

Comment: you could cut a LOT of that code. `$codes = file('codes.txt'); shuffle($codes); file_put_contents(implode(PHP_EOL, $codes));` plus what's the point of writing out your file, deleting the $codes array, then reading back in the exact same file you just produced? you already had the numbers in the array to start with.

Comment: a relational db would solve this in a flash

Comment: In addition, why write the shuffled array to a file line by line? maybe use `implode` to join it on a carriage return and write that out?

Comment: Each time this file is loaded, I need a static list of a randomized order of the `codes` array. That order will need to be used again for the next time the file is loaded by the same user

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't worry about a new array, $codes already has them.  If you need to close, reopen the file and read them into a new array, and memory is the issue, then kill the old array first by using `unset($codes)` before opening the file.

```
ini_set('memory_limit', '2048M');

// Get all of the values from the .txt file
// and store them in an array
$file = fopen("codes.txt", "r");
$codes = array();

while (!feof($file)) {
    $codes[] = trim(fgets($file));
}

fclose($file);

// Randomize the elements in the array
shuffle($codes);

// Write each element in the shuffled array to a new .txt file
$new_file = fopen("new_codes.txt", "w");
foreach($codes as $k => $v){
    fwrite($new_file, $v.PHP_EOL);
}

fclose($new_file);
```